# How do I make my array made in function global in C?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, global, local

```
void enterTwoArrays()
{
    printf("Enter m!\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter n!\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[m][n];

    printf("Enter m2!\n");
    scanf("%d",&m2);
    printf("Enter n2!\n");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    int arr2[m2][n2];

    for(i=0; i<=m-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n-1; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<=m2-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n2-1; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr2[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void addition(int arr[m][n], int arr2[m2][n2])
{
    int arr3[m][n];
    for(i=0; i<=m-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n-1; j++)
        {
            arr3[i][j]=arr[i][j]+arr2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Hey, I do have a problem. I got these two functions in C. The idea is that in the 1st function I will create and fill arrays. And the 2nd function will add values of two arrays. But when I try to, program crushes. I think I know where the problem is. Its cuz my arrays are kind of local and I cant send them to the 2nd function from main later. So how do I solve that problem ? I cant declare these arrays before in main/be4 main without knowing n and m variables.

Comment: You could pass pointers to the arrays.

Comment: pass pointers to arrays as arguments in your functions.

Comment: I see nothing inherently wrong with your code itself, but it does depend on `m2` and `n2` to be at least as large as `m` and `n`, respectively.  If that is not the case on a given run, then function `addition()` will attempt to access `arr2` outside its bounds.  Perhaps you should instead read only one common set of dimensions, and use it for both arrays.

Comment: Correction: you do have an error, but it is not related to passing arrays to `addition()`.  Where you input the elements of array `arr2`, you pass the array elements where you need to instead pass pointers to them.  That is, `scanf("%d",arr2[i][j]);`  -->  `scanf("%d",&arr2[i][j]);`.

Comment: At one level, you can't make the arrays defined in the functions into global variables.  All else apart, the storage allocated for the arrays is deallocated when the function returns, and reused by other functions.  Additionally, you can't have variable-length arrays at global scope.  It isn't clear you can even have pointers to variable-length arrays at global scope — I think not.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a pointer globally and allocate memory after taking the row and column from user. Here I have taken the same row and column for both matrix because that is a necessary condition for addition of matrices.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *arr;
int *arr2;
int row;
int col;
void enterTwoArrays()
{
    int i,j,t=0;
    printf("Enter rows!\n");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Enter cols!\n");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    arr=(int*)malloc(row *col *sizeof(int));
    arr2=(int*)malloc(row *col *sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter the first matrix:\n");

    for(i=0; i<(row*col); i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",(arr+i));
    }

    printf("Enter the second matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<(row*col); i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",(arr2+i));
    }

}

void addition(int *arr, int *arr2)
{
    int *arr3;
    int i;

    arr3=(int*)malloc(row*col*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<row*col; i++)
    {
        *(arr3+i)=*(arr+i)+*(arr2+i);
    }

    printf("The matrix after addition is: \n");
    int j,t=0;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++,t++)
        {
            printf("%d ",*(arr3+t));
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
}

void main()
{
    enterTwoArrays();
    addition(arr,arr2);
}
```